# JSON get line out of file

Tags: c#, json

i want to get these Line out of JSON in C#

```
    [
    {
        "License1": {
            "Description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
            "Value": "1"
        }
        
       
    }
]
```

So, i want to get the Description of License1

My code right now is this;

```
  string json = wc.DownloadString(".....licenses.json");

                
                dynamic dobj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(json);
                string kek = (string)dobj["License1.Description"];

                
                Console.WriteLine(kek);
                Console.ReadLine();
```

It works fine without the Argument: "License1.Description", so how can i get of License 1 the Description?

Comment: `dobj[0].License1.Description`

Comment: 1. Don’t use WebClient as this is deprecated for a decade now. Use HttpClient instead. 2. Don’t use dynamic, use a proper model class instead which gives you type safety, better performance and code completion/Intellisense.

Comment: Why don't you use JsonConvert.DeserializeObject from Newtonsoft.Json, and put data from json in object?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
string kek = dobj[0].License1.Description;
```

Dynamics are objects where you forgo type safety. They are otherwise working exactly as objects.

Since you deserialize from array access with the indexer `[0]` your object and get the properties as usual.